# Choosing 3 of 5 objects in one of two groups from 12 objects in several groups

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given a pool of 12 objects divided into 5 groups (see table), what is the probability that, when 5 objects are randomly chosen from the pool, exactly 3 of them belong to group *A* or exactly 3 of them belong to group *B*?

```
Group | Objects
  A   |    3
  B   |    4
  C   |    2
  D   |    1
  E   |    2
```

My current solution involves finding the independent probabilities of choosing 3 from group *A* and from group *B* and adding them together:

$$
\begin{align}
P(3 \subset A) &= \frac3{12} \cdot \frac2{11} \cdot \frac1{10} \cdot \frac99 \cdot \frac88 \\
&= \frac14 \cdot \frac2{11} \cdot \frac1{10} \\
&= \frac1{220} \\
\\
P(3 \subset B) &= \frac4{12} \cdot \frac3{11} \cdot \frac2{10} \cdot \frac89 \cdot \frac78 \\
&= \frac13 \cdot \frac3{11} \cdot \frac15 \cdot \frac89 \cdot \frac78 \\
&= \frac7{495} \\
\\
P(3 \subset A) + P(3 \subset B) &= \frac1{220} + \frac7{495} \\
&= \frac{37}{1980}
\end{align}
$$

Though my textbook says the correct answer is $ \frac{13}{66} $, and provides no process for the solution. Is my solution correct, and if not, how is the number given by my textbook calculated?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig can you please elaborate? And given that my answer is incorrect, how would the correct answer be calculated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $\binom{12}{5}$ ways to select five of the twelve objects in the pool.

Let $A$ be the event that exactly three objects are selected from group A when five objects are selected from the pool of twelve objects.  Let $B$ be the event that exactly three objects are selected from group B when five objects are selected from the pool of twelve objects.

The probability that exactly three objects are selected from group A or exactly three objects are selected from group B when five objects are selected from the pool of twelve objects is 
$$\Pr(A \cup B) = \Pr(A) + \Pr(B) - \Pr(A \cap B)$$
Observe that $\Pr(A \cap B) = 0$ since it is not possible for a selection of five objects to contain exactly three objects from group A and three objects from group B since $3 + 3 = 6 > 5$.

For event $A$ to occur, all three objects in group A must be selected together with $2$ of the other $12 - 3 = 9$ objects in the pool, which can occur in 
$$\binom{3}{3}\binom{9}{2}$$
ways.    Hence, 
$$\Pr(A) = \frac{\dbinom{3}{3}\dbinom{9}{2}}{\dbinom{12}{5}}$$

For event $B$ to occur, three of the four objects in group B must be selected together with $2$ of the other $12 - 4 = 8$ objects in the pool, which can occur in 
$$\binom{4}{3}\binom{8}{2}$$
ways.  Hence,
$$\Pr(B) = \frac{\dbinom{4}{3}\dbinom{8}{2}}{\dbinom{12}{5}}$$

Since events $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive,
$$\Pr(A \cup B) = \Pr(A) + \Pr(B) = \frac{\dbinom{3}{3}\dbinom{9}{2} + \dbinom{4}{3}\dbinom{8}{2}}{\dbinom{12}{5}} = \frac{148}{792} = \frac{37}{198}$$
which means the answer in the textbook is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected that the correct solution involved in/exclusivity but wasn't sure how to apply it. My textbook has several other incorrect answers so this is no surprise.